# Google Sheets Decimal Numbers, how to remove commas and add zero

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, number-formatting

Following problem. I have decimal numbers in my Google Sheets that I get from a website.

The numbers have 3 digits after the decimal point or they have no comma in there. I need the numbers without a comma and adding Zero after 1,2 => 1200 or 1,22 => 1220 and 2 should be 2.

Say if a number looks like this on the website:

```
1,200
1,220
1,222
12,220
2
```

I get the data via Google spreadsheet with the formula =IMPORTDATA("API_LINK")

There is the problem that the zeros that I don't want to lose are automatically deleted by =IMPORTDATA

Means I get that copied into the table like this :

```
1,2
1,22
1,222
12,22
2
```

My question is, how do I get the numbers to be automatically converted with another formula or even with a script that looks like this:

```
1,2 => 1200
1,22 => 1220
1,222 => 1222
12,22 => 12220
2 => 2
```

So normal numbers should be normal and decimals should be converted.

The formula what I tried but is only working for 1,222 => 1222. The other looke like this 1,2 => 43862 and 1,22 => 1,22 also 12,22 => 12,22.

```
=IFERROR(VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(A2;",";"."));VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(A2;".";",")))
```

I tried even to change the settings in the sheet but isn't working at all.
It would be very nice if someone could help me with that.

Comment: I won't be able to check since I got comma for decimal delimiter, but what about `INT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",".")*1000)`

Comment: This formula is working as I should be for the decimals, I forgot to say i've also normal numbers in there like 2 and 2 should stay as 2. But with this formula I get 2=>2000 and this is not right. I edited my question, thanks for this formula!

Comment: The problem here is that your API and your Google spreadsheet are not agreeing on the "locale" of the data.  European "decimals" are commas, whereas in the US, commas are just used between groups of "thousands".  I would recommend that you use File>Spreadsheet settings to change your spreadsheet to the locale of the SOURCE of the data.  See if the scrape comes in a lot more cleanly that way.  If so, there may be a btter workaround than a bunch of text substitutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your import is removing final zeros, this indicates that what winds up in your sheet is most likely text and not a number at all.

It is *always* easier to help if you share a sample sheet with full editing permissions. However, given what I know from your post, try this:

```
=IF(A2="","",VALUE(A2&IFERROR(REPT("0",3-(LEN(A2)-FIND(",",A2))))))
```

This would also work as an array formula with slight modification (i.e., it could "solve" a whole column with one formula rather than dragging a formula down). For instance, if your raw data were in A2:A, you could put the following array formula in B2 (assuming column B is completely blank below B2):

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A="","",VALUE(A2:A&IFERROR(REPT("0",3-(LEN(A2:A)-FIND(",",A2:A)))))))
```

Comment: This one fixed my problem. Thank you.

Comment: Great. Thanks for reporting back.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(TO_TEXT(IMPORTDATA("API_LINK")), ",", ))
```

Answer (score 0):

You also can use format patterns.

You can define how many digits wants in the decimal side with TEXT function. In this case, always three digits even zeros:

```
##.000
```

Then, once you have the number you want, you can remove the decimal separator with the SUBSTITUTE funtion.

Finally you got:

```
SUBSTITUTE(TEXT(YOURNUMBER;"##.000");",";"")
```

More info in this [google site](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/formats).